# AJAX div not updating without alert call with error: b.data is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dom-events

First of all, any suggestions on rewriting my title?

Issue:
I have an AJAX updatable div, when my error checking `alert` calls are in, everything works perfect.  But when I remove a specific one, the DIV never gets updated.  I know it sounds confusing, but code is as follows, and then I will explain further.

*AJAX SCRIPT*

```
var xmlhttp
    /*@cc_on @*/
    /*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
      try {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
     } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
      } catch (E) {
       xmlhttp=false
      }
     }
    @else
     xmlhttp=false
    @end @*/
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
     try {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } catch (e) {
      xmlhttp=false
     }
    }
    function myXMLHttpRequest() {
      var xmlhttplocal;
      try {
        xmlhttplocal= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
     } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttplocal= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
      } catch (E) {
        xmlhttplocal=false;
      }
     }

    if (!xmlhttplocal && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
     try {
      var xmlhttplocal = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } catch (e) {
      var xmlhttplocal=false;
      alert('couldn\'t create xmlhttp object');
     }
    }
    return(xmlhttplocal);
}

function sndReq(page,key,includesDir,changeDiv,parameterString) {
    var divToChange = document.getElementById(changeDiv); // the Div that the data will be put into
    
    // Place loading image in container DIV
    divToChange.innerHTML = '<div class="loading">Loading</div>';
    
    if (includesDir == 1){
        //Find Current Working Directory.  Use to find path to call other files from
        var myloc = window.location.href;
        var locarray = myloc.split("/");
        delete locarray[(locarray.length-1)];
        var arraytext = locarray.join("/");

        xmlhttp.open("POST","AJAXCaller.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(parameterString);
    
    } else {
        
    }
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse(changeDiv);
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
}

function handleResponse(changeDiv) {
/* ======== If I remove the following line script halts ================*/
/* ======== If line stays here, script executes perfectly ==============*/
    alert('to changetext 1\n'+xmlhttp.responseText);
/* =========End of line removal issue =================================*/       
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

        if (xmlhttp.status == 200){
        
        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

        var update = new Array();

            if(response.indexOf('|') != -1) {
                update = response.split('|');
                changeText(update[0], update[1]);
            } else {
                changeText(changeDiv, response);
            }
        
        } //End IF xmlhttp.status == 200
        

    }
}

function changeText( div2show, text ) {
    // Detect Browser
    var IE = (document.all) ? 1 : 0;
    var DOM = 0; 
    if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >=5) {DOM=1};

    // Grab the content from the requested "div" and show it in the "container"
    if (DOM) {
        var viewer = document.getElementById(div2show);
        viewer.innerHTML = text;
    }  else if(IE) {
        document.all[div2show].innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

When I check my Firefox error console, this error ONLY appears when I remove that alert as defined in the code:

```
Timestamp: 5/30/2012 5:07:55 PM
Error: b.data is undefined
Source File: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/wmd.js?v=cfd2b283af83
Line: 92
```

I am an advanced PHP/mySQL developer, but have been trying hard to grasp AJAX/JavaScript.  Doing tutorials like mad.  So please be descriptive in comments/answers so I can use them as a reference for learning...

Why would displaying an alert box alter code execution (for the better!) in any way?

***NEW ERRORS - Google Chrome and Firefox Console (sigh...)***

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
sndReqAJAX.js:89
element.onclick
```

Line 89 is the following (verified by Google Chrome Console)

```
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Everything I find on the web refers to extremely complex issue regarding DOM objects not existing...  This wouldn't apply here, would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the problem. This is the line:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse(changeDiv);
```

The reason this is wrong is that `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` should be a function - you need to assign a function to the property, what you are doing is calling the function and assigning the return value to the property. This is not in itself a problem, as long as your function returns a function. Which it doesn't.

If you're used to working with PHP (especially if your used to working with PHP <5.3) you may not be used to this concept. Javascript has support for closures in a way that anyone who doesn't use them much will find confusing.

What the line needs to look like is this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
```

By appending `(changeDiv)` you are *calling* the function, whereas what you need to do is simply pass it, like you would any other value.

Now, where it gets complicated is that you want to pass an argument that is local to the scope of the calling function. There are a number of ways to handle this, but a cursory look at your code tells me that `handleResponse()` is not used anywhere else, so it would be better to define this as a closure and not litter the global scope with a named event handler. This also overcomes the variable scoping problem:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
      var update = []; // "new Array()" is baaaad
      if (response.indexOf('|') != -1) {
        update = response.split('|');
        changeText(update[0], update[1]);
      } else {
        changeText(changeDiv, response);
      }
    } //End IF xmlhttp.status == 200
  }
};
```

Replace the aforementioned offending line with that block of code, and remove the `handleResponse()` function definition, and that should solve the immediate problem. Now, as to why the `alert()` "fixes" your original code - this is a little hard to explain, but I shall have a go... *give me a minute to inspect the code properly*

---

Attempt at a full and comprehensible explanation abandoned. If anyone wants one, post a comment and I'll have another go at it when I've had some sleep...

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  I have heard closures referenced, but until now was absolutely baffled by the terminology, and all web references I saw seem to assume that a person would know what they were, thanks!  I will test now...

Comment: A ["closure"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) is a subset of the concept known as an ["anonymous function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). You can [use them in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as well (since 5.3). In simple terms, one assigns a function to a variable instead of naming it. In Javascript this is actually one and the same thing, it's a very interesting in that respect.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  So just so I understand clearly...
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange is a function in itself that will fire each time the readyState changes, and will execute whatever is on the right of the `=` each time the readyState changes?  Thus it's basically a function calling a function, and will repeatedly execute until the readyState no longer changes?

Comment: `onreadystatechange` is a way to assign a handler to the xmlhttp object's `readystatechange` *event*. Every time this fires (usually 4 times, hence the `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {` check) the function that is assigned to that property is called. You could have simply remove the parenthesis and used the named function (functions can be passed around by name in the same way as variables in JS, technically they *are* variables in so much as anything is, in fact they are *members of the* `window` *object* - in a browser, at least)...

Comment: ...but because you needed the variable from the parent function (`sndReq()`) it is much easier to define a closure within the parent function, because then you inherit it's scope. Sort of. It is amazing how different JS is to PHP when on the face of it they look very similar.

Comment: OK, I'm really struggling to come up with an explanation of *why* the alert was "fixing" your code without it sounding like gibberish. Basically the alert box was halting the execution of the current "thread" of Javascript code (there are no threads in Javascript) allowing the HTTP request to finish, populating the variables that needed data for the handler to execute correctly. You see? Gibberish...

Comment: Yeah, with your changes the code works great except for the javascript console error I keep getting, although it doesn't seem to interfere with anything...  Will append it to the question in a second...

Comment: @MaurerPower I can see what is wrong about it - it did strike me as odd last night - but in order to really understand what the right way would be I need to understand that `if` block - most notably whether there will ever be any code to go inside the `else` block?

Comment: the else block was created due to a very strange error I was getting where the called page would contain data, but it would result in an array, and would fail.  After spending what seemed like an eternity fiddling with it, I created the else statement for the purposes of handling odd cases like that.  And it worked fine...  Still I was receiving that error before I created the else statement.

Comment: @MaurerPower Right, no worries - what you need to do is remove the line `xmlhttp.send(null);` and move the last three lines of the `if` block into it's place. It must be said, the rest of the code in the `if` block doesn't actually *do* anything, because you never use any of the values you create.

Comment: And FYI, `locarray.pop();` does exactly the same thing as `delete locarray[(locarray.length-1)];` in a much cleaner way